# NoMethodError: private method `open' called for Gem::Package:Class An error occurred while installing rake (10.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, bundler

I am trying to work on a ruby on rails project I synced from github. Even though rake-10.0.3 gets installed successfully, 'bundle install' fails. I am new to rails and not sure how to proceed on this.I googled the error, and tried the installing different versions of rake as suggested by the solutions, but it did not help.

Here's what I am trying to do... Please help.

`ruby 1.9.3p374 (2013-01-15) [i386-mingw32]`

```
>rails s
←[31mCould not find kaminari-0.14.1 in any of the sources←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m

>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

NoMethodError: private method `open' called for Gem::Package:Class
An error occurred while installing rake (10.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.

>gem install rake -v '10.0.3'
Successfully installed rake-10.0.3
Done installing documentation for rake (1 sec).
1 gem installed

>bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..

NoMethodError: private method `open' called for Gem::Package:Class
An error occurred while installing rake (10.0.3), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.0.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10741421/976775

Comment: Are you using rvm or ebenv?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You should first update Rubygems:

```
gem update --system
```

And then update Bundler:

```
gem install bundler
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, and sorry for the delay in reply.
It got resolved after i unistalled and re-installed ruby on rails...

Comment: For posterity: had this exact same issue and this solution solved it, unlike most other stuff.

Comment: You also really need the second step even though you'd already have the same version of Bundler already installed.