# How to resolve bundle install rake error and Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

When I run `bundle install` on ruby 2.1.2 I get:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

When I run `gem install rake` I get:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundle' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed
```

When I run `which bundle` I get:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global/bin/bundle
```

This error is preventing me from doing development work on localhost:3000 before deploying.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Feel free to up-vote this question if it was helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of Ruby or at least a newer version than the one you have. I was using 2.0.0-p247 and received the same error. When I upgraded to 2.2.5 (which is the oldest supported version at the time of this writing) then everything worked.

I also had to run `gem install bundler` after upgrading ruby. Last, I'm using rbenv and installed ruby with `rbenv install 2.2.5` then ran `rbenv local 2.2.5`.

Comment: When I answer this question version 2.2.5 doesn´t exist. So my answer to this specific question at that time is correct.

Answer (score 14):

In the Gemfile in your rails application directory change:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
```

to

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
```

Comment: This seems to work out partially.  I get the following: 'Your bundle is complete! Gems in the group production were not installed.'  But I still get the following error and I still don't get access to localhost:3000:  ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Using http is insecure and could result in trojan gems.